# Why $\sin\,z$ does not have a pole at $z=\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

I believe that $\sin\,z$ does not have a pole at $z=\infty$. But how to prove it? I think we can use the fact that $\sin\,z$ have a pole at $z=\infty$ if and only if $\sin(1/z)$ has a pole at $0$. But how to show $\sin(1/z)$ does not have a pole at $0$? Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the Taylor series for $\;\sin\frac1z\;$ : you get an essential singularity.

Comment: If $\infty$ were a pole, you would get $\lim_{z\to\infty}\sin z=\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

The singularity at $\infty$ is not a pole:  it is essential.

This is a fact that is easy to prove:  consider the limit $$L(\theta) = \lim_{r \to 0^+} |\sin(re^{i\theta})^{-1}|.$$  For $\theta = \pi k$ for some integer $k$, this limit is bounded in the interval $L(\theta) \in [0,1]$.  If $\theta$ is not an integer multiple of $k$, this limit is $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a sequence $z_k$ tending to infinity for which $\sin z_k = 0$ for every $k$, the corresponding sequence $1/z_k$ shows that $\sin(1/z)$ does not tend to infinity at the origin - hence, no pole.

---

Alternative way: Show that a function has a pole at infinity if and only if it's a non-constant polynomial. This is a good exercise in Liouville's theorem.

Now note that $\sin$ has infinitely many zeros, so it's not a polynomial.